# How do I expand /dev/sda3 and volume group from the command line?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

We're running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS as a VM under Hyper-V - no UI, so gparted isn't really an option.

We were running low on space on /dev/sda3 so I expanded the drive inside of Hyper-V, then ran:

```
sudo parted -l
```

It warned:

Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can
fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 20971520 blocks) or continue with
the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? Fix

After fixing, I see running fdisk -l that /dev/sda is now 100 GiB.

It's not really clear to me how to assign this extra space to /dev/sda3 - I tried just expanding the logical volume that is at 99% usage (the one that prompted me to try to expand the space available in the first place):

```
sudo lvextend /dev/srv-vg/root /dev/sda3
```

But I think that since the space isn't assigned to sda3 it can't expand it (as it didn't really expand it).

So then I tried parted:

```
$sudo parted /dev/sda
resize part 3
End?  [85.9GB]? -0
(parted): quit
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab
```

fdisk -l now shows sda3 has more space, but it still shows that 99% of the space is used.

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424  488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 209715166 207665119   99G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/srv--vg-root: 77 GiB, 82703286272 bytes, 161529856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I tried lvextend again:

```
sudo lvextend /dev/srv-vg/root /dev/sda3
```

but it says this:

```
  No free extents on physical volume "/dev/sda3".
  No specified PVs have space available.
```

I rechecked vgdisplay:

```
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               srv-vg
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  3
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                2
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               79.02 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              20229
Alloc PE / Size       20217 / 78.97 GiB
Free  PE / Size       12 / 48.00 MiB
VG UUID               HvKrjH-VGRA-svAB-NOmW-f23C-7uwq-hdh5Ja
```

It feels like I'm almost there, but I'm not seeing what else I need to do to expand this.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Each time You are playing with disks You have to go through these stages:

1. extend/modify storage device (VM disk in Your case)
2. sometimes there is a need for OS/kernel partition table refresh
   (reboot is sure and easy step)
3. extend/modify partition table of that partition
4. again, refresh partition table (via blockev or partprobe command
   or reboot)
5. now You cand extend your filesystem and youre done or continue...
6. in case of LVM or so is now time to use PV, VG and finally LV
   resize commands

So You are probably looking for a missed step of:

**pvresize/vgextend** in the case You have successfully resized the correct partition

And if the partition is still not resized?

Use **fdisk** (, cfdisk, sfdisk, parted, -gparted-, ..) to resize this partition.
  It will be easy if it is the last one partiton on the disk (neverless the type GPT/MBR).
  I usually delete that one partition and re-create it as bigger.

Try **pvdisplay, vgdisplay** commands and look what shows $ **cat /proc/partitions**
If You dont see Your free space here it probably still isnt assigned to the right partition.

PS: If You are not sure always do the BACKUP